# How can I shut down my AWS ElasticBeanstalk env at night?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have several production applications running on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, but I also have testing environments running in similar beanstalk environments.

I'm wondering how I could shut down those environments at nights while nobody's working on them?

I want to implement a simple **lights on/off** switch to save costs on AWS resources that are in use only while people are actually working on them (lab).

Answer (score 1):

## Tutorial to shut down auto-scaling (EC2) at night:

> Note: you can use this guide for scaling up and down at times, shutting down and restarting, just change the configuration.

1. Navigate to

   - Elastic Beanstalk
   - Environment
   - Your-environment
   - Configuration
   - Instance traffic and scaling
2. Collapse 'instances' or scroll down to 'Capacity'

[image: EBS Capacity]

3. Scroll a little further down to 'Time-based scaling'

[image: Time Based Scaling]

4. Add scheduled action
5. Add one action for shutting down, one for restarting

   - For the recurrence (cron-job): `minutes hours days weeks months`
   - Example, every day 07:00am: `0 7 * * *`
   - Example, every day 07:00pm: `0 19 * * *`
   - Shut down: all capacities to 0
   - Starting: all capacities to your desired value

[image: Example scheduled action]

6. Add a similar action for restarting
7. Make sure your end-date is correctly configured. If you want to be safe, make sure the startup script is running at least one day longer than the shutdown script to make sure you don't end up forgetting why your environment went down forever.

Answer (score 0):

there's a [Time-based Scaling configuration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/05/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-time-based-scaling/) in Beanstalk